# How do you get the active element using Waypoint?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jquery-waypoints

I'm using Waypoint (7.3.2) in React (16) to try and create a list of scrollable items where each item fades to invisible as it reaches the top of the div.  My basic question is how do I get a reference to the element that enters/leaves the waypoint in the event or callback?

I thought that by including `ref={}` in the element I wanted to get in the callback I would get a reference to the element and be able to change the opacity. The following is the code where Waypoint is plugged in:

```
class Division extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    _handleWayPointEnter = (event) => {
        console.log("Waypoint enter " + JSON.stringify(event, 4));
    }
    _handleWayPointLeave = (event) => {
        console.log("Waypoint leave " + JSON.stringify(event, 4));
    }

    render() {
        let inlineStyle= {opacity : this.state.opacity};
        return (
            <Waypoint debug={false} onEnter={this._handleWayPointEnter} onLeave={this._handleWayPointLeave} >
                <div style={inlineStyle} ref={this.props.innerRef} className="sch-division">
                    {this.props.name}<br/>
                    <SomeOtherComponent />
                </div>
            </Waypoint>
        );
    }

}

export default Division;
```

Any/all replies appreciated!

-- griff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From react-waypoint docs :

> If you do pass a child, it can be a single DOM component (e.g. `<div>`)
>   or a composite component (e.g. `<MyComponent />`).
>
> Waypoint needs a DOM node to compute its boundaries. When you pass a
>   DOM component to Waypoint, it handles getting a reference to the DOM
>   node through the ref prop automatically. If you pass a composite
>   component, you need to make use of the innerRef prop passed by
>   Waypoint to your component. Simply pass it through as the ref of a DOM
>   component and you're all set. Like in this example:
>
> ```
> class Block extends React.Component {
>   render() {
>     return <div ref={this.props.innerRef}>Hello</div>
>   }
> }
> Block.propTypes = {
>   innerRef: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
> }
>
> const App = () => (
>   <Waypoint>
>     <Block />
>   </Waypoint>
> )
> ```

Here you're using a single DOM component (`<div>`), i suggest you store your div ref like this :

```
<div style={inlineStyle} ref={(div) => { this.divinwaypoint = div; }} className="sch-division">
```

Then use it in your functions :

```
_handleWayPointEnter = (event) => {
   console.log("Waypoint enter " + JSON.stringify(event, 4));
   this.divinwaypoint.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

Edit: i'm not using waypoint but i think it should display your component ref in the `event` prop.

Comment: Dyo, this definitely gives the reference in the callback. Thanks for that. It doesn't really solve my overall problem because all the elements that are visible are in the waypoint to start.  So I think that I need to rethink where my waypoint is at.  -- Thanks for the reply!